# Why did the defected bulb glow brighter when switched off?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity

Suddenly an LED bulb in my house stopped glowing (actually it  was having very little brightness (can be noticed in the video)). But when I switched off the bulb , **it first glows brighter** and then went off. This was not accidental , whenever I repeated this I got the same result.

Here's the [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/4k1vQmLX6_c?feature=share)

***So why did the bulb get brighter when switched off ?***